# Determine absolute path of module without using require

Tags: perl

In some cases you need to determine the absolute path name of a Perl
module, but you do not need to load the Perl module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mod_name = 'My::Module';
my $abs_path = mod_name_to_abs_path( $mod_name );

sub mod_name_to_abs_path {
    my ( $mod_name ) = @_;

    my $rel_fn = $mod_name =~ s{::}{/}gr;
    $rel_fn .= '.pm';
    require $rel_fn;

    return $INC{$rel_fn};
}
```

The above code loads the module (with `require`).

How can I determine the absolute path name of a module without using require?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Module::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Util) module provides the `find_installed` function which does what I think you need.

There is also the object-oriented [`Module::Info`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Info) and [`Module::Data`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Data) modules which will do something superficially similar

This program shows the use of all three

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Module::Util 'find_installed';
use Module::Info ();
use Module::Data ();

say find_installed('Module::Util');

say Module::Info->new_from_module('Module::Info')->file;

say Module::Data->new('Module::Data')->path;
```

#### output

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\Util.pm
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\Info.pm
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Module\Data.pm
```

Comment: Sounds like it does.

Answer (score 7):

I am posting this solution to my own question since I could not find a CPAN module that did this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;

my $mod_name = 'My::Module';
my $abs_path = mod_name_to_abs_path( $mod_name );

sub mod_name_to_abs_path {
    my ( $mod_name ) = @_;

    my $rel_fn = $mod_name =~ s{::}{/}gr;
    $rel_fn .= '.pm';
    my $abs_path;
    for my $dir (@INC) {
        if ( !ref( $dir ) ) {
            my $temp = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $rel_fn );
            if ( -e $temp  ) {
                if ( ! ( -d _ || -b _ ) ) {
                    $abs_path = $temp;
                    last;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $abs_path;
}
```

Comment: You should explain the differences between what this does and what Perl does (`if !ref($dir)`).

Comment: Also, why don't you create a CPAN module so it can be maintained in one place rather than in everyone's code base.  [ Seems like simbabque beat me to it :) ]

Comment: Looks reasonable. References in `@INC` only get there if you put them there, so I'm not sure that that part is completely necessary, but I guess it doesn't hurt anything. I'd also suggest `-e && ! -d` as the file test, which is what Path::Tiny does.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will look into them!

Comment: It really doesn't matter what Path::Tiny does. It's what Perl [does](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/443bd156a6baaf7a8fe6b6b05fcf6c4178140ed2:/pp_ctl.c#l3587) that matters.

Comment: What Perl does is `st_rc = PerlLIO_stat(p, &st); if (st_rc < 0 || S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) || S_ISBLK(st.st_mode)) { return NULL; }` (`stat` + `-d` + `-b`) and then tries to `open` it.

Comment: Also, `require` doesn't always search `@INC`. I believe neither `require "/foo/bar.pm"` nor `require "./foo/bar.pm"` will use `@INC` (but `require "foo/bar.pm"` will).

Comment: I'm pretty sure too that `require "./foo/bar.pm"` ignores `@INC`. On top of that, even if there is a `foo/bar.pm` in the working directory, it will load it again, because it uses its argument as the key for `%INC`. That way, you can `require` the same thing twice (but not more). Essentially a poor man's `do`. Or a good way to shoot yourself in the foot.