# Is there a way to tell which @INC path a module was loaded from?

Tags: perl

***Use case***

My sysadmin just installed a Perl module via `rpm` and despite the fact that I can successfully `use` it in a one-liner, I want to know where the module was installed.

I can obviously comb through each of the path locations in `@INC`, but is there a way for Perl to tell me where it successfully loaded the module from?

Comment: `perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say Dumper \%INC'`

Comment: See also [Determine absolute path of module without using require](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41707660/2173773)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the `%INC` hash is for. It shows you where a module was loaded from.

```
$ perl -MDBI -MData::Dumper -E'say Dumper \%INC'
$VAR1 = {
          'XSLoader.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/XSLoader.pm',
          'warnings/register.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/warnings/register.pm',
          'List/Util.pm' => '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/List/Util.pm',
          'warnings.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/warnings.pm',
          'DBI.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DBI.pm',
          'overloading.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/overloading.pm',
          'Config.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/Config.pm',
          'Carp.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Carp.pm',
          'bytes.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/bytes.pm',
          'Exporter/Heavy.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Exporter/Heavy.pm',
          'Scalar/Util.pm' => '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Scalar/Util.pm',
          'strict.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/strict.pm',
          'Exporter.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Exporter.pm',
          'vars.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/vars.pm',
          'constant.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/constant.pm',
          'overload.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/overload.pm',
          'DynaLoader.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm',
          'Data/Dumper.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm',
          'feature.pm' => '/usr/share/perl5/feature.pm'
        };
```

**Update:** Actually, there's an easier method.

```
$ perldoc -lm Your::Module
```

Comment: If you omit the `-m` and your module contains no POD, you'll get "no documentation found" rather than the path.

Comment: Note that the `Foo/Mod.pm` key format is used on Windows too. Using `( $pkg =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . '.pm'` is portable. (See the [if](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?if) module for some corroboration.)